# Trying to Host my discord bot on heroku But I can't get The worker . Please Tell me how to fix this and where

Tags: heroku, discord.js

Hello So I made my discord bot Bolt and tryed to host it on heroku
1.I used to host a simple bot before on herkou and it used to work fine
2.Now If I try I don't get the option to make the dyno to worker

Please tell me how to fix this and where

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question but it seems like you want the bot to run as worker. If that is the case then you can make a file named `Procfile` in your bot's directory and add something like this inside it:

```js
worker: node index.js
```